# Get Employee Details SQL Query from three tables

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I have 4 tables:

- EMPLOYEE - Having ID,EMPID,PRJOID(FOREIGN KEY),DEPTID(FOREIGN KEY),IMGURL,NAME,..OTHER FIELDS.
- EMPLOYEE_LOGS - Having EMPID,TYPE(IN/OUT)(FOREIGN KEY),LOGTIME
- PROJECT - Having ID,PROJECTID,PROJECTNAME
- DEPARTMENT - Having ID,DEPARTID,DEPARTNAME

I try to get employee details like :

QUERY FOR = Get DEPTNAME and no.employees and no.IN and no.OUT based on PROJECTID
   QUERY FOR = Get EMPLOYEENAME and latesttime(LOGTIME) and TYPE(IN/OUT) based on DEPTID.

Comment: Google "SQL SELECT" and "SQL JOIN", and then make an effort to do this yourself first. You can then [edit] your question here to add some sample data, the output you'd like to get from that data, and the attempt you made at doing it yourself, and we can try to help. Good luck.

Comment: Sure that you use qt? That [tag:qsqlquery] tag you are using points to that.